# Create a desktop shortcut to the currently viewed web page in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, desktop, shortcuts

Is it possible to create a shortcut to a web page on the desktop from Google Chrome? I remember that Internet Explorer had a feature like this, does it exist in Chrome as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Just drag the globe in the left-hand corner of the omnibar to your desktop

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04, this appears to create a full copy of the webpage, and not a shortcut to the web page. Is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Well that's weird (works in windows, which isn't saying much); it's supposed to just be a shortcut to the url itself. Are you using `chromomium` or `google-chrome`? (they have subtle differences). I'll check on my Mageira in a sec

Comment: I'm using google-chrome. BTW, what's a Mageira?

Comment: Different linux flavour (don't worry about it). Anyway; when I drag-drop to desktop it gives me the option to link, copy or move. Dunno why it's different for you D:

Comment: When I drag and drop it onto the desktop, it creates a file that contains a copy of web page's source (basically, a local copy of the web page). I'm surprised that it works correctly on Windows but not on Ubuntu (or Linux Mint).